# How can I filter ALL twig output without changing any templates?

Tags: laravel, twig

In Laravel, I would like to filter all output of all Twig templates globally without changing any of my templates. The case at hand is that I want to convert all http:// and https:// in all html my application generates to a protocol-relative //.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how one would do this?

The quickiest and dirtiest way I can envision doing this is at the point that twig is rendering html. just do a regexp.

I've stared hard at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html but I'm not sure if my answer is really in there. I also tried tracing how the |raw filter works, because I figured there is a transformation happening that |raw actually *suppresses*, which is (if accurate) in the ballpark of the kind of thing I want to do. I got to a certain point and decided to ask someone.

Thanks

Comment: Add your filter to web/app.php.  That will certainly get everything.  A more conventional approach would be to create a kernel.response listener.

Comment: And in what framework you want to do it? You put 2 frameworks tags but haven't mentioned any of them in your question

Comment: you're right thank you Marcin. the answer is Laravel, question is edited.

Comment: for the moment, I have hardcoded a hack into bundles/twigview/view.php to run a preg_replace on the rendered html before it is printed to the page. would be nice to put this somewhere extension-like and not in the lib. But I did find *a* way.

Answer (score 0):

Twig really isn't the place to do such a transform as it will apply to all output your application is sending. I recommend that you look into the [Event System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events) provided by Laravel. You should be able to catch the Kernel's response event and then filter the output in your listener. I've done the same thing in Symfony to implement similar functionality.

If your paths are being generated by or put through a twig filter, you can look at extending those particular filters for your use case, however, this seems really fragile to me because what happens then if someone has hardcoded a path in a template rather than using a variable?